# how to generate random lottery numbers

Tags: python-3.x

hi i'm new to python i want to generate random lottery numbers and assign them to a list of five names (1 ticket for each name) I'm using Python 3.10

```
import random
lotteryNumbers = []
for i in range(0, 6):
number = random.randint(1, 50)
while number in lotteryNumbers:
number = random.randint(1, 50)

lotteryNumbers.append(number)
lotteryNumbers.sort()

print(lotteryNumbers)
```

How do i generate 5 lottery tickets and assign them to a list of 5 people
Thanks

Comment: We shouldnt be doing your homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
lotteryNumbers = [None] * 5
finalArray = [None] * 5
j = 0
while j < 5:
    for i in range(0, 5):
        number = random.randint(1, 50)
        lotteryNumbers[i] = number
    finalArray[j] = lotteryNumbers
    lotteryNumbers = [None] * 5
    j+=1



print(finalArray)
```

Edited My bad